# Subset pandas DataFrame based on a bin

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to subset a pandas DataFrame, based on a binned category. (I know you can subset based on the values themselves, this is just a representation of a different problem that I actually do need to bin the data!) I think I'm missing something about the subsetting, but can't find it out what in the documentation. Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(9876)

# Generating random data for binning.
bin_step = 0.5
random_data = np.random.uniform(low = 0, high = 10, size = 30)

# Generating bin ranges
bin_ranges = np.arange(start = random_data.min(), 
                           stop = random_data.max() + random_data.max()*0.1, 
                           step = bin_step)

# Cutting the random data into predefined bins.
bins = pd.cut(random_data.tolist(), 
              bin_ranges,
              right = True,
              include_lowest = True)

# Aggregating into a pandas DataFrame
random_data_pd = pd.Series(random_data.tolist(), name = 'values')
bins_transformed = pd.Series(bins, name = 'bins')

df = pd.concat([bins_transformed, random_data_pd], axis = 1)
```

When subsetting the bins, for example `(5.086, 5.586]`, it's returning all `False`. Why does this not subset?

```
df.bins == '(5.086, 5.586]' #returns all false.
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: One of the bins is '(1.455, 1.955]', so I'd expect that specific bin to be True

Comment: Could you please add a seed to NumPy to try and reproduce your error? I cannot reproduce this issue.

Comment: Added in now. I just used that interval as an example, but I've tried with other intervals with no luck.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I don't see an interval that would match (pandas 0.19.2), the nearest interval is `'(5.0865, 5.586]'`. Assuming you aren't misreading the intervals, what Pandas version are you using?

Comment: I'm using pandas 0.20.1, but I am using Python 2.7, not sure how that might affect this.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding correctly, the reason why is that you're using `==` to different types, `pd.Interval` vs `str`. Please check my example.

```
print(type(df.bins[0]))

<class 'pandas._libs.interval.Interval'>

print(df.bins)
print(df.bins == pd.Interval(5.1, 5.2))

0     (1.586, 2.086]
1     (6.086, 6.586]
2     (8.586, 9.086]
3     (7.586, 8.086]
4     (5.086, 5.586]
5     (0.585, 1.086]
6     (4.586, 5.086]
7     (1.086, 1.586]
8     (9.086, 9.586]
9     (4.586, 5.086]
10    (1.586, 2.086]
11    (1.086, 1.586]
12    (2.586, 3.086]
13    (2.586, 3.086]
14    (1.086, 1.586]
15    (8.086, 8.586]
16    (7.086, 7.586]
17    (6.586, 7.086]
18    (8.586, 9.086]
19    (7.586, 8.086]
20    (7.586, 8.086]
21    (0.585, 1.086]
22    (4.586, 5.086]
23    (9.086, 9.586]
24    (8.086, 8.586]
25    (6.586, 7.086]
26    (5.086, 5.586]
27    (6.586, 7.086]
28    (5.086, 5.586]
29    (9.086, 9.586]
Name: bins, dtype: category
Categories (19, interval[float64]): [(0.585, 1.086] < (1.086, 1.586] < (1.586, 2.086] <
                                     (2.086, 2.586] ... (8.086, 8.586] < (8.586, 9.086] <
                                     (9.086, 9.586] < (9.586, 10.086]]
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
16    False
17    False
18    False
19    False
20    False
21    False
22    False
23    False
24    False
25    False
26     True
27    False
28     True
29    False
Name: bins, dtype: bool
```

subset...

```
print(df[df.bins == pd.Interval(5.1, 5.2)])

              bins    values
4   (5.086, 5.586]  5.132422
26  (5.086, 5.586]  5.309666
28  (5.086, 5.586]  5.574920
```

Comment: Is it possible to do what you've done, but treat the interval as a Category variable?